# Alternate form of derivative to find derivative at $x=c$

Tags: calculus

Use the alternate form of the derivative (Theorem 3.1) to find the derivative at $x=c$ (if it exists).

The derivative of $f$ at $c$ is given by

> Theorem 3.1:
>
> $f'(c)= \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ provided this limit exists.

$f(x)=|x-2|$, $c=2$

Comment: Have you plugged that function in for $f(x)$ and tried to evaluate the limit?  Have you tried plotting the function?

Comment: it may be helpful to think about "what the solution should/will be" (simply draw a graph for your function $f$).

Comment: I was unsure about the absolute values

Answer (score 1):

HINT: plugging the given term in the formula $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ you will get $$\frac{|x-2|}{x-2}$$ if $x\ne 2$ then you must distinguish two cases, $x>2$ or $x<2$